# How to read jailbreak syslog?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, syslog, crash-log

0
How to understand why gvidi app is fall at start up? I have a crash log, but i cant read any helpful inforamtion from it.

```
========================

ASL is here to serve you

Mar 13 14:28:13 iPhone-5 ubd[25644] <notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.apple.ubd [ubd] (793.00)

Mar 13 14:28:13 iPhone-5 ubd[25644] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/IAPFreeService.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:22 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: ru.gvidi [Gvidi] (793.00)

Mar 13 14:28:22 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:22 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/CameraTweak.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:22 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/FullForce.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:22 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Nitrous.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:22 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/OctopusKeyboard.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:22 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/WinterBoard.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:22 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector setIconLabelAlpha:

Mar 13 14:28:22 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:23 iPhone-5 SpringBoard[25531] <warning>: [TWEAK: ALOUD]: Now playing info: (null)

Mar 13 14:28:23 iPhone-5 locationd[54] <notice>: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'

Mar 13 14:28:23 iPhone-5 wifid[29] <error>: WiFi:[384863303.489445]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"

Mar 13 14:28:23 iPhone-5 wifid[29] <error>: WiFi:[384863303.545222]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"

Mar 13 14:28:23 iPhone-5 wifid[29] <error>: WiFi:[384863303.554465]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"

Mar 13 14:28:23 iPhone-5 wifid[29] <error>: WiFi:[384863303.600043]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"

Mar 13 14:28:24 iPhone-5 backboardd[25523] <warning>: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long

Mar 13 14:28:24 iPhone-5 kernel[0] <debug>: AppleAP3GDL::checkDataAvailable:414 DRDY was set after 0 iterations

Mar 13 14:28:24 iPhone-5 backboardd[25523] <warning>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence 28ee3

Mar 13 14:28:24 iPhone-5 SpringBoard[25531] <warning>: CoreAnimation: failed to receive fence reply: 10004003

Mar 13 14:28:24 iPhone-5 kbd[69] <warning>: -[TIXPCDataTransport _handleForPurpose:withReplyBlock:] couldn't get data source for purpose=__TIRDTAB

Mar 13 14:28:24 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <warning>: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL

Mar 13 14:28:24 iPhone-5 securityd[25647] <notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [securityd] (793.00)

Mar 13 14:28:24 iPhone-5 securityd[25647] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/IAPFreeService.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [ReportCrash] (793.00)

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/IAPFreeService.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ubd[25651] <notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: com.apple.ubd [ubd] (793.00)

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ubd[25651] <notice>: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/IAPFreeService.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd5e9b0=""> 946670BB-1CC2-3B74-B9E7-436CAF7DA1BA /var/mobile/Applications/E485C474-5A49-4C99-BA87-4722C3B5CAC4/Gvidi.app/Gvidi

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd5eb80=""> A059EB89-4E62-3EC0-9D63-294C525FF7A2 /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd5f8a0=""> B0D1162A-8AB0-3529-BB90-E416895B568A /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd60690=""> 12DAEF21-4FD2-3415-8028-C97C22DC5CCA /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd60ff0=""> 15676E2E-E142-3F59-8907-FF49FCEDE85B /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd61f40=""> 0562A59B-DF8D-3F77-83E9-3F35D7E724A8 /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd62ad0=""> 55826212-D8B4-352B-87D8-0F93BC9B25C6 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd635c0=""> DBD4F278-C71B-3F21-9DA3-E895B1F6AC80 /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd63ea0=""> 83291308-3F7F-347F-BA13-40263FF13B52 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd64d70=""> 584E0454-42BE-39FC-847F-FE1A5E4C99B2 /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd65f70=""> 5E7169AD-0185-3BD0-BA0F-66648A67A010 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd66cd0=""> 7109F645-A9CA-3A49-97B4-172AED228723 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd67560=""> 81D69724-6510-3FA3-B85B-4125F0AD33F1 /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd68390=""> 53AB26B3-1971-35A7-81D5-5819FD80F032 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd68e60=""> ED43D4DB-46A4-3DB0-976E-EAC5F3BC77A1 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd699a0=""> 137C1FBC-6A84-3D36-9038-348255635111 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <warning>: FAILED: dyld LOAD of <cssymbolowner: 0x1dd6a750=""> 30360E7D-98A3-3F92-8545-1FE4C54CE112 /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/IAPFreeService.dylib

Mar 13 14:28:25 iPhone-5 ReportCrash[25649] <notice>: Formulating crash report for process Gvidi[25646]

Mar 13 14:28:28 iPhone-5 locationd[54] <notice>: received EBUSY, try kScanTypeChannel, channel, 12, rssi -60, delayed 0.000s
```

Comment: This is not quite a crash log. Do you happen to have a stack trace?

Comment: Yeah.. . Its a syslog. But its all i have.. Not my device6 just one user send me it and say "app do not work"..

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be indicated by this line:

```
Mar 13 14:28:24 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <warning>: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
```

But without your source code it's hard to say for sure. The problem may be something similar to what's addressed [here](http://www.alexmedearis.com/nskeyedunarchiver-initforreadingwithdata-data-is-null/): perhaps you're attempting to save data somewhere, but not ensuring that it's saved to disk, and then trying to read it back in later? In any case, look at anywhere that you're calling the initForReadingWithData method, and ensure that there's no way its argument could be null, in any use case.

Comment: Thx for answer, but i sure problem isn't in this place cuz i know what is it and case with nil object is catched and workarounded..
Application works fine on all devices, but its first time than user tell "On my Jail Break device its always crash" and all what he give - sys log.

Comment: This is another possibility: `Mar 13 14:28:22 iPhone-5 Gvidi[25646] <warning>: MS:Warning: nil class argument for selector setIconLabelAlpha:`. But again debugging just based on syslog is almost impossible. You can ask them to send you the crash log (they're saved on the iPhone, at least with jailbreak iPhones). Or you can include more debugging logs to the syslog, push out an update, and ask the person to let you know if it still crashes, and have them send you the log again.